# Jquery attr('style') and addClass() not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="sidebar_holder"><div>
```

Now i want to set the style attr and class dynamically using jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var s = $("#sidebar_holder");
            s.attr("style", ""); //kill absolute positioning
            s.addClass("stick"); //stick it
```

Comment: Div doesn't have `style` attribute so how it will kill positioning? Your code seems fine. Also which version of jQuery you are using? jQuery 2.x supports ie9+

Comment: you are using different object first `jQuery` in ready document and then `$` in var define.. set it same ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment,

> You are using different object first `jQuery` in ready document and
>   then `$` in var define.

and try this, 
may help you

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var s = jQuery("#sidebar_holder"); // make this same as used before..
  s.attr("style", ""); //kill absolute positioning
  s.addClass("stick"); //stick it
```

You are using different object first `jQuery` in ready document and then `$` in var define.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

s.css("position", "");

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/)

```
s.removeAttr("style");
s.addClass("stick");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this it may be helpful for you

```
$("#sidebar_holder").removeAttr("style");
$("#sidebar_holder").addClass("stick");
```